# Font promblem in file dialog using xfce

Tags: fonts, xfce

In certain apps (like Opera browser) file dialog shows squares instead of chars. I'm using XFce. Using Ubuntu-Regular font everywhere and always encoding in UTF-8. I read somewhere it is fault of XFce because it picks up wrong font but I'm unable to find solution. Do someone knows how to solve this issue ?

It looks like this :
[image]

As requested in comments, here is output of  inxi -Fxxxz

```
System:    Host: GarromMachine Kernel: 4.15.0-30-generic x86_64
           bits: 64 gcc: 7.3.0
           Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3 (Gtk 2.24.31) info: xfce4-panel dm: lightdm
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: LENOVO product: 80EW v: Lenovo B50-80 serial: N/A
           Mobo: LENOVO model: Lenovo B50-80 v: SDK0J40700 WIN serial: N/A
           UEFI [Legacy]: LENOVO v: A8CN47WW(V3.00) date: 07/14/2015
           Chassis: type: 10 v: Lenovo B50-80 serial: N/A
Battery    BAT1: charge: 28.5 Wh 100.0% condition: 28.5/28.5 Wh (100%)
           volts: 15.9/14.4
           model: 4C 47 43 00 31 31 7E 0F 7E 003041344C33314C Li-ion serial: <filter>status: Full cycles: 0
CPU:       Dual core Intel Pentium 3825U (-MT-MCP-) 
           arch: Broadwell rev.4 cache: 2048 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 7582
           clock speeds: min/max: 500/1900 MHz 1: 1057 MHz 2: 969 MHz
           3: 959 MHz 4: 805 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel HD Graphics bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:1606
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
           drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Broadwell GT1
           version: 4.5 Mesa 18.1.3 (compat-v: 3.0) Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel Broadwell-U Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:03.0 chip-ID: 8086:160c
           Card-2 Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Def. Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 chip-ID: 8086:9ca0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-30-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIE Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 3000
           bus-ID: 08:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168
           IF: enp8s0 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Intel Wireless 3160
           driver: iwlwifi bus-ID: 09:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:08b4
           IF: wlp9s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (5.0% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST500LT012 size: 500.1GB
           serial: <filter> temp: 36C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 111G used: 20G (19%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 4.21GB used: 0.00GB (0%)
           fs: swap dev: /dev/sda6
RAID:      System: supported: N/A
           No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
           Unused Devices: none
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 39.0C mobo: 39.0C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 203 Uptime: 22 min Memory: 1269.1/3864.4MB
           Init: systemd v: 237 runlevel: 5 default: 2 Gcc sys: 7.3.0 alt: 5
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.191 running in xfce4-terminal) inxi: 2.3.56
```

Comment: 1) Sure, I'm on it 2) It is 35, I like it because it is last version which is not filled with features which I never need 3) Only opera, I had other program which had it like too, but I uninstalled it and can't recall name 4) Can't remember, It was random page I found during(unsuccessful) looking for solution.

Comment: Hi. Problem with opera 35 is, it forcefully required libcurl3 meanwhile most applications require libcurl4. I avoided problems by launching file browser as root and copied folder (unzipped) below to my usr folder. Originaly it was for my personal needs but I'll share it with you.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PDiTCVIDuEYIxqCdoTX3-MjxXIKqdiXl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @DKBose I had tryed many fonts, even seting them in my system too, aswell as many encodings.  If I change font, it affect look of boxes so fonts works... well, except it missing every character. I even tried MS fonts from ubuntu-restricted-extras.

Comment: @DKBose Oh.... yeah, 36, sorry, my bad. If it is not issue with XFCE, what is problem then ?

Comment: I think it's going to be difficult to figure out with a browser that is no longer supported.